# The definite article before family members

Tags: definite-article

In terms of meaning, what is the difference (if there is one) between these sentences:

1. Grandmother buys a new belt.
2. The grandmother buys a new belt.

Comment: In the first sentence (assuming the omission of the article is not a mistake), I can only assume that *Grandmother* is being used as if it were a proper noun. In other words, that's what her family members call her.

Answer (score 1):

**Grandmother** there is a form of address, and is used like a name.

**The grandmother** refers to her position or role in the family.

Compare this caption for a hypothetical photograph:

> Sis gets her hair styled.

Answer (score 1):

"Grandmother" as a proper noun (similar to a name) suggests that it's the speaker's grandmother or a well-known grandmother character in a story, and furthermore that there is only one grandmother in question. If there are multiple grandmothers one would refer to them with additional name, like "Grandma Jill", or "grandmother Jones".

> Today we all went to the mall, and grandmother bought a new belt.

"The grandmother" uses "grandmother" as a noun. It can be used to refer to a person who is a grandmother and has been already mentioned before, but is not a significant character, or nor familiar enough to be called "grandmother" as a name.

> A girl and her grandmother went to the mall. The grandmother bought a new belt.